# How to use the HashTable in LeanTween?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Among the functions provided by LeanTween,
Is there a function that functions like iTeeen's RotateBy?
(RotateBy(GameObject obj,Hashtable hash))

What I want to do is, 
After completing the animation, the function is executed through the string.

For example, in a card-matching game,
If you click on the card, the following event will occur.

WordReviewManager.cs:

```
public void onTuchHandler(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    TouchEventTypes t_evt = e as TouchEventTypes;
    Debug.Log("GameObject : " + t_evt.go + " / " + "Card : " + t_evt.card);
    Debug.Log("Card Index : " + t_evt.card_idx + " / " + "Card UniqueIndex : " + t_evt.card_snum);
    Debug.Log("================================================================================");
    WordReviewUtil.testAni(this.gameObject, t_evt.go, t_evt.card, t_evt.delay, t_evt.complete);
}
```

The function that receives the event is shown below.

WordReviewUtil.cs:

```
 public static Hashtable testAni(GameObject listener, GameObject go, Card card, float delay = 0f, string complete = "testGood")
    {
        Debug.Log("hello TEST ANIMATION ~~ ");
        Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
        GameObject goz = go as GameObject;
        Debug.Log("goz >>>> " + goz);

        hash.Add("gameObj", goz);
        hash.Add("onComplete", complete);
        return hash;
    }
```

Here is what I expect to see afterwards.

WordReviewManager.cs:

```
   public void testGood(Hashtable table)
    {
        Debug.Log("hello Moto ~?!");
    }
```

That is, the testGood function is executed.

iTween has a function that gives me the functionality I want.

Immediately, RotateBy function.
But I am currently using the LeanTween library, not iTween.

Also, the LeanTween library does not provide the functionality I want.

I just need to call the function. Without any parameters.

How do I implement what I want to implement?

Comment: I don't get the question. You know what you want to do is in ITween so use ITween.

Comment: Didn't you understand my question? When I use LeanTween instead of iTween, what if I want to implement what I want?

Comment: I am saying that you want to use hashtable/oncomplete which is supported in ITween and not in LeanTween. So use ITween.

Comment: If iTween is not used, can not it be implemented? @UmairM

Comment: I would like to implement LeanTween. Because the plugin used in my project is LeanTween.. @UmairM

Comment: Look at LeanTween docs there is a method calld addListener you can use this as compared to onComplete in iTween

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main design change between [iTween](http://www.pixelplacement.com/itween/index.php) and [LeanTween](http://dentedpixel.com/LeanTweenDocumentation/classes/LeanTween.html) for the complete callback is that iTween takes the method name as string and internally calls the evil [SendMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) method.

LeanTween uses the [Action delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx), which can be considered as pointer to a method. You can see in WordReviewManager.Start() how you can just assign the testGood method to the field Action onCompleteCallback of TouchEventTypes and feed that into your system.

```
public class Card : MonoBehaviour { }

public class TouchEventTypes : EventArgs
{
    public Card card;
    public float delay;
    public Action onCompleteCallback;
}

public class WordReviewManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
        TouchEventTypes e = new TouchEventTypes();
        e.onCompleteCallback = testGood;
        //TODO: feed this into your touch event system.
    }

    public void testGood()
    {
        Debug.Log("hello Moto ~?!");
    }

    public void onTouchHandler(object obj, EventArgs e)
    {
        TouchEventTypes eventArgs = e as TouchEventTypes;
        WordReviewUtil.RotateCard(
            card: eventArgs.card,
            delay: eventArgs.delay,
            callback: eventArgs.onCompleteCallback
        );
    }
}

public static class WordReviewUtil
{
    public static void RotateCard(Card card, float delay, Action callback)
    {
        LTDescr tween = LeanTween.rotateAround(card.gameObject, 
            axis: new Vector3(0,0,1),
            add: 360f, 
            time: 2.0f
        ).setDelay(delay);
        tween.setOnComplete(callback);
    }
}
```